# cd directory_name python python_file.py gives error in command line " the system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, cmd

I am running python file from command line. To be more specific my .py file is in location F:\new_github_code\cocktail_party\data\audio\audio_downloader.py>. I want to run audio_downloader.py file from the cocktail_party directory not from the audio directory.
I tried by using the following script from cmd. Any help will be appreciate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6UIU.png)

Comment: If you don't use fully qualified paths you will always get these errors. This is so basic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work:

```
python data\audio\audio_downloader.py
```